# Make Helm Projectile to show external sources

Tags: helm, projectile, cc-mode, c, project

I'm pretty new to emacs (was using Vim), primarily using it for Ruby on Rails projects.

At my free time, I like to write some C code for STM32 micro-controllers.

Unlike RoR project, C project for STM32 contains a lot of external dependencies (includes) outside of project's folder, and there is as good reference documentation, so I have to read source codes a lot.

So, I would like to do `C-c p h` and find any random file including external dependencies.

I understand, that this task is more complex, than just writing `t` some variable, but I can't even realize, where can I start the research.

Another problem, that I don't want to hardcode dependencies list into my `~/.emacs.d`, it should be project-specific settings.

Comment: How, precisely, do I determine what external sources are? Will you simply tell Emacs to "search this folder too" or should Emacs detect it automatically from the includes?

Comment: I want just a way to setup an external folder for project manually. Actually, I think, that we may have some project-specific settings in the `.projectile` fie